# How support concurrent connections with a UDP Server using go

Tags: go

I'm playing with my first basic udp server and I wondering how support concurrent connections? I think with my code only can get a connection at a time in order to process it, with a tcp simple server the things seems to be more clear than on this case, throwing a goroutine to process the data, but here I'm  very lost, thanks in advance.

```
func main() {
    ListenerUDP("127.0.0.1", 1111)
}

func ListenerUDP(ip string, port int) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    log.Println("Listener Started!")
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: port,
        IP:   net.ParseIP(ip),
    }

    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error Listening:%s\n", err.Error())
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        _, remoteAddr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buffer[0:])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error:%s\n", err)
        }
        // Process data here? using a > go something()?
        fmt.Printf("Data:%s From:%v\n", buffer, remoteAddr)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UDP [is a connectionless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionless_communication)--hosts send packets without establishing a connection first.

To get multiple cores handling UDP packets in parallel, you might start a bunch of goroutines that each do the `ReadFromUDP` loop:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "runtime"
)

func listen(connection *net.UDPConn, quit chan struct{}) {
        buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, remoteAddr, err := 0, new(net.UDPAddr), error(nil)
        for err == nil {
                n, remoteAddr, err = connection.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
                // you might copy out the contents of the packet here, to
                // `var r myapp.Request`, say, and `go handleRequest(r)` (or
                // send it down a channel) to free up the listening
                // goroutine. you do *need* to copy then, though,
                // because you've only made one buffer per listen().
                fmt.Println("from", remoteAddr, "-", buffer[:n])
        }
        fmt.Println("listener failed - ", err)
        quit <- struct{}{}
}

func main() {
        addr := net.UDPAddr{
                Port: 12345,
                IP:   net.IP{127, 0, 0, 1},
        }
        connection, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        quit := make(chan struct{})
        for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
                go listen(connection, quit)
        }
        <-quit // hang until an error
}
```

Comment: With your code I'm getting a from 127.0.0.1:53236 - [] , but if I change buffer := make([]byte, 0, 1024) -> buffer := make([]byte, 1024) works fine.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. (I thought I said this before, but comment wasn't here when I came back, so...)

Comment: Is not the order of events lost, with this? (atleast the order as it is received to the program)

Comment: @JavaTechnical That's true--this isn't really right for applications trying to build persistent connections on top of UDP (like QUIC or such do) or otherwise do more than handle a packet at a time. Doing that correctly is a deep topic and might be material for a different question.

Comment: Good example of how to read UDP data in concurrence https://gist.github.com/jtblin/18df559cf14438223f93